# Count multiple columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, count

Table "orc"

```
P1        p2       p3         p4
__________________________________
w2        w2       w2         w1
w1        w5       w3         w7
```

Table "artg"

```
ref      design
_________________
w1        product1
w2        product2  
w3        product3
w4        product4
w5        product5
w6        product6
w7        product7
```

I need to count the P1, P2, P3 and P4 togheter.

Like output:

```
Design    Total
_________________
Product1     2
Product2     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Union All` to combine all columns of `orc` table to one column. Then find the count of each design and join it with `artg` table.

**Query**

```
select t2.design,count(t1.p) as Total 
from
(
    select p1 as p from orc
    union all
    select p2 as p from orc
    union all
    select p3 as p from orc
    union all
    select p4 as p from orc
)t1
right join artg t2
on t1.p = t2.ref
group by t2.design;
```

**Result**

```
+----------+-------+
| Design   | Total |
+----------+-------+
| product1 | 2     |
| product2 | 3     |
| product3 | 1     |
| product4 | 0     |
| product5 | 1     |
| product6 | 0     |
| product7 | 1     |
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Dont work, it get all the artg table, and dont count the orc table